# Using decimals in math functions in Python

Tags: python, math, decimal

`math` is a Python module used by many to do a bit more advanced mathematical functions and using the `decimal` module. One can calculate stuff correctly `1.2-1.1=0.0999~`, but using the `decimal` type it's `0.1`.

My problem is that these two modules don't work well with each other. For example, `log(1000, 10)=2.9999~`, but using a `decimal` type gives the same result. How can I make these two work with each other? Do I need to implement my own functions? Isn't there any way?

Comment: Can you keep your calculations entirely within the `decimal` module environment? E.g. `decimal.Decimal(1000).log10()` -> `Decimal('3')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `Decimal.log10`, `Decimal.ln` and `Decimal.logb` methods of each `Decimal` instance, and many more (`max`, `sqrt`):

```py
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal('0.001').log10())
# Decimal('-3')
print(Decimal('0.001').ln())
# Decimal('-6.907755278982137052053974364')
```

There are no trigonometry functions, though.

More advanced alternative for arbitrary-precision calculations is [mpmath](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath), available at PyPI. It won't provide you with `sin` or `tan` as well, of course, because `sin(x)` is irrational for many `x` values, and so storing it as `Decimal` doesn't make sense. However, given fixed precision you can compute these functions via Tailor series etc. with `mpmath` help. You can also do `Decimal(math.sin(0.17))` to get some decimal holding something close to sine of 0.17 radians.

Also refer to [official Decimal recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-recipes).

Answer (score 1):

There is a log10 method in Decimal.

```
from decimal import *
a = Decimal('1000')
print(a.log10())
```

However, it would make more sense to me to use a function that calculates the exact value of a logarithm if you're trying to solve logarithms with exact integer solutions. Logarithm functions are generally expected to output some irrational result in typical usage. You could instead use a for loop and repeated division.